# Removing "armv6" from Valid Architectures of Xcode.. what would be affected?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

I checked the table from the following page, if I remove "armv6" from Valid Architectures of Xcode, does it mean the app would fail to run on the iPhone1, 3G and iPod touch 1st, 2nd??  Is that so simple? 
Anything else would be affected? 
My game is Coco2ds-x

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll be safe removing the ARMv6 architecture from your project if you don't need to support those ancient devices - ARMv7 and later will let your app run on:

- iPhone 3GS and later
- All iPads, 'normal' and mini
- iPod Touch 3rd generation and later

I got most of this from Apple's [iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html), which is an awesome resource.

In fact, [Xcode 4.5 and later doesn't know how to build for the ARMv6 architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12474870/1849664). This is, in my opinion, a gentle nudge to developers to stop supporting old platforms, and instead keep up with what's new so they can make newer, faster, better apps.