# Failed Xcode build: no rule to process file for architecture armv6

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7, armv6

Building my iOS App in Xcode 4.5 results in Dependency Analysis Warnings for every source file:

```
warning: no rule to process file of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
```

This eventually results in a missing binary. Any ideas what's wrong here?

Build settings: *armv6 armv7* Valid Architectures and *iOS 4.3* Deployment Target.

Comment: check answers for following questions:

[Build for armv6 architecture (target iOS 3.1.3) with iOS 6 SDK and Xcode 4.5?][1] 

[Xcode 4.5 and iOS 4.2.1 incompatibility][2]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533544/build-for-armv6-architecture-target-ios-3-1-3-with-ios-6-sdk-and-xcode-4-5
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463195/xcode-4-5-and-ios-4-2-1-incompatibility

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xcode 4.5 does not support building armv6 binaries anymore.

Comment: Gotta wonder how much reputation will be gained from this answer scattered amongst a lot of questions.

Comment: No idea - but I'll keep telling people about it. ;)

Comment: ... the air must be thin up there. Is there a way to build armv6 compatible binaries with XCode 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

Set **Valid Architectures** to **armv7**.