# iPad Build Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios6, armv7

I am finding conflicting information about the armv of an iOS application. I am creating an **iPad only** application. The application should be able to **run on all iPads** (all three generations). The application has 5.1 as its deployment target.

I did not bother about all this until Xcode 4.5 showed up. I updated my Xcode (and hence the iOS simulator got updated as well to 6.0) when suddenly my application stopped working. I figured out  setting the 'Build Active Architecture Only' to 'Yes' allowed me to continue programming. I cannot stand the fact however to change settings without exactly knowing what they do. That's why I am stuck with following questions:

1. Does armv7 cover all iPad generations?
2. How come my application throws 'file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice' when setting 'Build Active Architecture Only' to 'No'? (This is when testing on a iPad 1.) Because I thought setting it to 'No' means you are generating a **fat binary**.
3. Which settings do I need eventually to run on all iPads? Are there multiple configurations possible (I assume not), and so, which are preferred?

Current settings are:

- Architectures: Standard (armv7, armv7s)
- Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 6.0)
- Build Active Architecture Only: Yes
- Valid Architectures: armv7 armv7s

Thanks for reading if you made it till this point.

Comment: armv7 does indeed cover all current iPad's (`original`, `2` and `new`).

Comment: Do you have your app set for `iPad` or `Universal`?

Comment: Also are you using any 3rd party libs? I had this issue with a 3rd party lib. What file does it say doesn't have the right slices?

Comment: The app is set for iPad (not universal). I am using 3rd party libs (Cocos2d, Parse, TestFlight). The file is: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o That seems to be the SDK I added to Xcode 4.5 manually. The app is working though on iPad 1 after distributing it ad-hoc...

Comment: I added SDK 5.1 because the app is built in this SDK. Switching to SDK 6.0 now would be too much of a cost to optimise for iOS 5 and iOS 6 (the version of Cocos2d used and SDK 6.0 don't go well together). But how come I cannot test iPad 1 (wired and with Xcode), but I can run the app when distributed through .ipa file....

Comment: related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463195/xcode-4-5-and-ios-4-2-1-incompatibility                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533544/build-for-armv6-architecture-target-ios-3-1-3-with-ios-6-sdk-and-xcode-4-5