# xCode 4.5 on Mountain Lion and Supporting apps running iOS 4.2

Tags: ios

Two questions:

1) Can Xcode 4.3 work on Mountain Lion?

2) If I upgrade Xcode to 4.5 on Mountain Lion then would I be able to support applications that were running iOS 4.3?

I believe if I upgrade to xCode 4.5 on Mountain Lion then I should be able to target old applications running iOS 4.3 with Non ARC code.

I guess it depends on the deployment target setting. In Xcode 4.5 it shows the deployment target of 4.3 as the oldest.

Comment: If you need to support armv6 devices (why most people need to target iOS 4.2), this question has your answers: ["Build for armv6 architecture (target iOS 3.1.3) with iOS 6 SDK and Xcode 4.5?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533544/build-for-armv6-architecture-target-ios-3-1-3-with-ios-6-sdk-and-xcode-4-5)

Comment: I updated the question! 4.3 not 4.2. 4.3 should work without any problems.

Comment: I would answer but you already gave yourself your own answer to the last half - the oldest deployment target in XCode 4.5 is iOS 4.3 regardless of OS X version.  XCode 4.5 does not have a 4.3 simulator though, you'll have to test that on a device.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner Hmm interesting! But can't I run an app whose deployment target is set to 4.3 on a iOS 6 simulator. If that causes a problem then I believe Xcode does allow to download legacy simulators.

Comment: Sure, you can run it on any later version of the simulator.  You just wont see any bugs that you would get with iOS 4.3, or find any crashes that would result from any API calls introduced later than 4.3.  If you claim your app supports 4.3 you really should at least try running it a few times on that version of a device - the app reviewers will...