# Is it possible to create an app iOS 4 - iOS 7 compatible with Xcode 5.0.2 on Mavericks?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, osx-mavericks

I need to develop an app who support iOS 4 - iOS 7, is it possible to do it on XCode 5.0.2 on Mavericks?

The lowest deployment target xcode provide me is iOS 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Project > Target > Build Settings > Architectures:

> change the **Architectures** from **Standard Architectures (including 64-bit)** to **Standard Architectures** ,or if you want to support older devices, type `armv6 armv7 armv7s` in Others

[image: Type it]

Then, you can change the deployment target to lower versions (just type `4.0` or `4.3` in the Deployment Target box)

But why do you want to target iOS 4 still?

Comment: I don't want iOS 4, however I got a contract with a company who want that the app will support iOS 4 god know why.
Anyhow thank you for your answer it is much appreciated.
One more question, if I'm adding armv6 architectures the app will support IPhone 3g as well?

Comment: last question, what about iOS 4 simulator?
and again thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Blacky you want to test on Simulator or Real Device? Xcode 5 does not have iOS 4 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, supporting iOS4 is possible, the problem is supporting ARMv6 (iPhone 3G and iPod Touch 2G).
To support ARMv6, you need iOS SDK 5.x with is available in Xcode 4.4.
But you also need to support the widescreen iPhone resolution, so you need to use [two different Xcode versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5) for it

Comment: Incorrect. `armv6` is still supported by Xcode 5. Just type the value in the "Architecture" box.

Comment: You can't compile it, iOS6.x SDK doesn't support it anymore.

Comment: No. I'm still using it & compile is fine (you can check Qualcomm's Vuforia SDK). They target `iOS 4.0` but I can still compile with Xcode 5.

Comment: And it can be installed on an iPhone 3G? Because i also can start the compiled app on an iPhone 3Gs with iOS 4.1, but not on iPod Touch 2G with 4.2.1

Comment: iPod Touch 2G is [armv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM11), maybe your deployment target is 4.3 ? or, what is the error ?

Comment: i said i could test on my 3Gs with iOS 4.1. It is bigger than 4.3, so that can't be the problem. Are you sure you using iOS SKD 6 and up?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580494/1293167

Answer (score 0):

Try this , You will get the deployement Target till from lowerEnd . Its mainly due to the >XCode 5.0 choses by default architecture as **including 64-bit** this only supports >IOS 6.0 [image]

`iPhone 5S is powered by A7 64bit processor`. From apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> Xcode can build your app with both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries
>   included. This combined binary requires a minimum deployment target of
>   iOS 7 or later.
>
> Note: A future version of Xcode will let you create a single app that
>   supports the 32-bit runtime on iOS 6 and later, and that supports the
>   64-bit runtime on iOS 7.

Comment: With 64bit it support 5.1.1 and up, not 6.0 and up