# Any issues in updating iOS 4 app to iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios8, app-update

I have an iOS 4 app I developed 4 years ago that needs to run all iOS versions from 4 to 8.  What is the best way to go about that.  All I can think of is just go through all compiler failures and fix them while if I use any feature not present in iOS 4 I have to to do if else condition for using the feature/class etc.

Is there anything else I need to worry about?

I read this question and it is helpful but I am wondering what else.
[Is it possible to create an app iOS 4 - iOS 7 compatible with Xcode 5.0.2 on Mavericks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327333/is-it-possible-to-create-an-app-ios-4-ios-7-compatible-with-xcode-5-0-2-on-mav)

Comment: depending on how complex the application is, I would recommend to rewrite it instead of patching up from iOS4 – but the question is which way would be more cost-efficient for you in long term.

Comment: Actually when I opened it on Xcode 5 I didn't have to do anything except relinking one library and fiddling with architectures, base SDK and deployment target.  It now runs on all devices from iOS 4.3.3 to 8.0.2