# How to use .a's built in lower version with Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, .a

Can I use .a's built with Xcode 4.3.3 in Xcode 4.5? When I build with simulator it is building fine, when I'm build for device it is showing many reference error. What I am suspecting is .a's I'm using is older. Am I right. Is there any way I can fix this problem instead of building all .a's with Xcode 4.5.

thanks.

Comment: hard to know without much detail, but this is probably related to Xcode 4.5 dropping support for armv6 architecture. Do you have access to the source to rebuild on Xcode 4.5?

Comment: No I don't have source now. I have to request for that :(

Comment: OK simplest way is to ask, but in the meantime, try [this](http://blog.chpwn.com/post/31824877081)

Comment: It looks tricky, Ill try :). Can you please add this link as answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an issue with using a library which was build supporting armv6, which has been dropped in Xcode 4.5

The best long term solution is to ask the developer who created these libraries to rebuild to support the latest Xcode, but in the meantime you can try following [these instructions](http://blog.chpwn.com/post/31824877081)

Comment: Thank You for your answer. One more doubt, If I build with Xcode 4.5, can I use that application in lower version of IOS? or Will it create problem like this?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12463536/1138900) has a good summary of which versions you can support and how