# how to change iOS deployment target to 4.2 on xcode 4.5.1?

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

I just installed Xcode 4.5.1 and I want my projecto in iOS deployment target 4.2, but it just show 4.3, any idea how can I change to 4.2??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Xcode 4.5.x only supports iOS 4.3 and later. Xcode 4.5.x no longer supports armv6 devices. armv6 devices only support up to iOS 4.2.1.

Apple wants everyone to move forward. If you want to support iOS 6, you need to drop 4.2 and earlier. This means no 1st or 2nd gen iPod touch, no iPhone, or iPhone 3G.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3461:

> Changes in Xcode 4.5.x
>
> - Xcode 4.5.x (and later) does not support generating armv6 binaries.
> - Now includes iPhone 5/armv7s support.
> - **The minimum supported deployment target with Xcode 4.5.x or later is iOS 4.3.**

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this answer [stackAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13061562/1050722). According to that, you can deploy for lower targets. I'm just downloading an older Xcode version to try it out...