# Develop for ios 4.2 on xcode 4.5

Tags: ios4, xcode4.5, ipod-touch, ios-4.2

I've got one old ipod touch 2g which can be upgraded just to 4.2.1.
I also have xcode 4.5 which says:

> Unsupported device Devices of type “iPod touch (2nd generation)” are
>   not supported by this version of Xcode.

Is there any way I can develop for this poor old device on my current version of xcode?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the lowest iOS version developers can create an app for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069384/what-is-the-lowest-ios-version-developers-can-create-an-app-for)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your targets > summary > deployment target and set it to 4.3 or greater.

Go [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463195/xcode-4-5-and-ios-4-2-1-incompatibility) for earlier

Comment: the oldest is 4.3 and it says:  "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

Comment: OK, I've tried to install old xcode version on my mountain lion and got unrepairable kernel panic at each boot. so I've restored system from time machine backup and would not recommend anyone to install very old xcode on mountain lion