# Discovering the version of iOS of an iOS Binary

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to know for which version of iOS a given application was compiled by inspecting its iOS binary or another file inside the app package?

thanks

Comment: Do you have just the binary, or the whole app package?  Because if you have the package, the stuff in `Info.plist` would probably tell you.

Comment: AHA!!!! This is the only file I have not inspected. So, now I have learned that XCode 4.5 is able to compile to 4.x iOS!!!! Even if this choice is not on the deployment target list, just type the version you want it to be compiled! Thanks. Please add your comment as an answer, so I can accept.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want to target iOS 4 because you still want to target `armv6` devices, just manually changing the deployment target isn't enough.  You'll need to [do something like what I discuss in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13061562/119114).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the whole package, and not solely the compiled binary, one of the keys inside `Info.plist` would probably tell you.

Comment: Looks like it's the `MinimumOSVersion` key inside Info.plist.